# Which libraries are needed to use hibernate 4.2.0?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I searched on Google but each tutorial says different jar libs. Is there a full list of jar that I could have in order to use Hibernate correctly (on Eclipse)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at maven repository.
You need all the jars that in the /lib/required/ directory. the others are for support for more fitchers like JPA and etc.
but for basic app you can use this jars for version 3 is:

- hibernate3.jar (main jar)
- antlr-2.7.6.jar
- common-collections-3.1.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1
- jta-1.1.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar (for jpa)

Here is a good tutorial for hibernate: [java brains](http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/hibernate.html)

Comment: The linked website is gone. The https://web.archive.org has [a copy of the website](https://web.archive.org/web/20130328024153/http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/hibernate.html). The archived version shows black squares instead of the embedded YT videos.
Its seems tho, that these are also available in [this YT playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yv2xctJxE-w&list=PL4AFF701184976B25)

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_environment.htm

Following is the list of the packages/libraries required by Hibernate and you should install them before starting with Hibernate. To install these packages you would have to copy library files from /lib into your CLASSPATH, and change your CLASSPATH variable accordingly.

dom4j - XML parsing www.dom4j.org/

Xalan - XSLT Processor http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/

Xerces - The Xerces Java Parser http://xml.apache.org/xerces-j/

cglib - Appropriate changes to Java classes at runtime http://cglib.sourceforge.net/

log4j - Logging Faremwork http://logging.apache.org/log4j

Commons - Logging, Email etc. http://jakarta.apache.org/commons

7SLF4J - Logging Facade for Java http://www.slf4j.org